# Error message: End of script output before header while using MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, cgi-bin

I am trying to implement MYSQL in python cgi-bin. I dont know why this is coming.
I am doing this on windows 8 and python version 2.7.8. I also visited different but fail to solve.

File name: **sqlcgi.py**

My code:

```
#!C:\Python27\python
import cgi
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",port=3306, user="root", passwd="",db="project")

cursor = db.cursor() #for 1st query
cursor2 = db.cursor()##for 2nd query
# execute SQL select statement
#sql = "SELECT stid,firstname FROM student WERE stid IN(SELECT stid FROM stobt WHERE stid=%s" % (0) #query number 1

#query number 1
sql2 = "SELECT stid FROM student  WHERE firstname = '%s'" % ('User')


# Execute the SQL command

cursor2.execute(sql2)
# Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.

result2 = cursor2.fetchall()
print result2

row2 = result2[0]
#print 'r1',row[1]
#print 'r2',row2[0]
sql = "SELECT * FROM stobt  WHERE stid = '%d'" % (row2)
cursor.execute(sql)
results = cursor.fetchall()
row = results[1]
tc = 56
for row in results:

   if row2[0] == row[1]:
      idd = row[0]
      stid = row[1]
      obtained = row[2]
      subject = row[3]

   # Now print fetched result
      print "id=%s,stid=%s,obtained=%f,subject=%s" % \
             (idd, stid, obtained, subject )

      if obtained <= 50:
         if tc >= 50:
            print tc
print """Content-type: text/html\n

<html><head><title>MySQL and Python on the Web</title></head>
<body bgcolor=#FFCCFF><h1>Message Board Report</h1>
This is a message board report demo.<hr>
<b>This is what has been going on ... </b><br>
"""

print idd

print """
<hr>
<form method=POST>Please enter your comment: <input name=info><br>
<input type=submit>
</form>
<hr>
Demonstration from Well House Consultants.<br>
<a href=http://www.wellho.net/>Website</a>
</body></html>
"""

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

Error:

```
Error message: 
End of script output before headers: sqlcgi.py
```

I dont know whether i am doing wrong or correct because when i remove all sql section and cgi prints but with sql does not.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error somewhere before the first output statement, and your script is aborting.

It will help to find it if you enable trace back reporting. Add this to the top of your script:

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
```

When you load the page in a browser, you should see what the error is.

There are also other problems with your script. In a CGI script, standard output is sent as the HTTP reply. Importantly the HTTP headers must be written first, before the actual content.

In this case you have some debug print statements, e.g. line 22, that generate output before the HTTP headers are printed.

Comment: not getting can u suggest thru code? may be i m understanding wrong

Comment: i ve 1st placed print """Content-type: text/html\n at top but did nt succeed like u said

Comment: #!C:\Python27\python
import cgi
import MySQLdb

print "Content-type: text/html\n"
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",port=3306, user="root", passwd="",db="project")

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor2 = db.cursor()

Comment: Just comment out lines 22, 41, 42, & 44-46. These are the print lines before you emit headers.

Comment: OK, sorry, I picked up on a different error to the one that you're experiencing. I'll update the answer...

Comment: @Malik: I have updated the answer again to enable traceback display with the `cgitb` module. It should help you to discover what is wrong in your script.

Comment: i added in the same way but no trace display

Comment: @Malik: did you try to remove the `#!C:\Python27\python` line?

Comment: after removing i got this error:
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

Comment: I don't know what else to advise you then. Does the script run without error if you execute it separately, i.e. `python sqlcgi.py`? What is the output when run separately?